# Excel VBA: changing visible cells based on names cell value. Works once then not again

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a spreadsheet to show a set of names rows called authorisations when there is no project number in the project ref cell but if a project number is added to the cell the authorisations are not required and should disappear.

If the cell is blank and the row visible then when project reference is added the rows disappear but if I then delete that reference and change cell they do not reappear.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Project_Ref = "" Then
Range("authorisations").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
Range("authorisations").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

I have tried a search online and found comments that adding Application.EnableEvents = True before the End sub should help but it didn't seem to make a difference. I am now wondering if Worksheet_change in fact operates as I thought it did where it would look for any changes in the sheet and then execute the code if required.

Comment: EnableEvents is enabled by default so unless you disable it at the beginning of your code, it won't do anything. I don't think that's your problem though. Where are you assigning the Project_Ref variable? Is it a global variable? If it's a range named "Project_Ref", it should be Range("Project_Ref")

Comment: That seems to have solved my problem. Thank you